# force close when editing TextView from different class

Tags: java, android, textview, settext, forceclose

I want to edit TextView in **Class A** with data from spinner from **Class B**

**Class A**

```
TextView tvv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ClassA);
tvv = findViewById(R.id.tv_sel1);

public TextView getTextView() {    
        TextView tv = tvv;
            return tv;
       }
}
```

**Class B**

```
select1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Select 1 - "    +parent.getSelectedItem().toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ClassA txt = new ClassA();
                TextView tv = txt.getTextView();
                tv.setText(parent.getSelectedItem().toString());

            }
```

when I run "debug" whit prints, app force close on

```
tv.setText(parent.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

So I put the text in wrong format or is there some other mistake?

Comment: you will need to pass this data with a putextra from class b to class a, then get that value and simply put it inside your setText

Comment: yet another ... where `ClassA.onCreate` is called?  nowhere ... which obviously will cause NPE when you would like to use `getTextView` ... please learn some android basics: do not create `Activity/Service/Application` derived class  by yourself with operator `new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class A u should set a method to set the text on the textvieuw:

**Class A:**

```
public void setText(String text) {    
    tvv.setText(text);
   }
```

**Class B:**

```
ClassA.setText(parent.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: this is working with some edit, I am using void now because i have nothing to return or should I?

Comment: yeah you should, that's the right usage for void, edited my answer for that so other people don't get mistaken by that